# Synchronize 2 sql server 2019 database over intermittent connection (no replication)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm a PostgreSQL DBA learning SQL Server 2019.

**The setup :**

- 1 Desktop, 1 Laptop
- Both running SQL Server 2019 Developer
- Windows 10 Home (nothing else, no active directory, nas, san, ...)
- a database in simple recovery model, with partial containment enabled

**The problem :**

- I want to be able to synchronize a database from my laptop to the desktop, or the other way around
- I don't want to use replication (log shipping or others) since I may not connect both servers for a long time and my laptop is very limited in disk space. (I'm in simple recovery model for the same reasons)
- both (desktop/laptop) database must be writable (so no primary/secondary)
- if the database is modified on both side, I'll lose modification on one side. It's ok! I accept this.

**The solution I know :**

- Create a SQL Server dump, send it to the desktop over shared network, apply the dump. or the other way around.

**Is there a way to export a database to another database, on demand ? Or is the dump/transfer/restore the way to go ?**  (that's what I would do with PostgreSQL)

I don't know all the SQL Server keywords and terminology and my google-fu was unsuccessful. Most solutions I find are obviously about how to set up replication over a reliable/permanent network. which doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: now that i think about, i haven't looked at any "import" option, there might be a more readily available option to import data from another database, instead of the other way around (exporting to a database)

Answer (score 0):

Well... it turn out it couldn't be easier.

```
Right click on database -> Tasks -> Copy database...
```